# Rotate Globe.gl globe (with react-three-fiber or otherwise) in React

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, webgl-globe

I'm following this [example](https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl/blob/master/example/airline-routes/us-international-outbound.html) from Globe.gl to achieve the following [output](https://globe.gl/example/airline-routes/us-international-outbound.html). I want to rotate this globe using react-three-fiber, namely using the approach from this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rrppl0y8l4?file=/src/App.js:0-1187).

Here is my `Globe.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3-dsv";
import indexBy from "index-array-by";
import Globe from "react-globe.gl";

import earth from "../../public/images/earth-dark.png";
import background from "../../public/images/globeBackground.png";

function GlobeHome() {
  const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;
  const globeEl = useRef();
  const [airports, setAirports] = useState([]);
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);
  
  const COUNTRY = "United States";
  const OPACITY = 0.125;
  const airportParse = ([
    airportId,
    name,
    city,
    country,
    iata,
    icao,
    lat,
    lng,
    alt,
    timezone,
    dst,
    tz,
    type,
    source,
  ]) => ({
    airportId,
    name,
    city,
    country,
    iata,
    icao,
    lat,
    lng,
    alt,
    timezone,
    dst,
    tz,
    type,
    source,
  });
  const routeParse = ([
    airline,
    airlineId,
    srcIata,
    srcAirportId,
    dstIata,
    dstAirportId,
    codeshare,
    stops,
    equipment,
  ]) => ({
    airline,
    airlineId,
    srcIata,
    srcAirportId,
    dstIata,
    dstAirportId,
    codeshare,
    stops,
    equipment,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      fetch(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat"
      )
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((d) => d3.csvParseRows(d, airportParse)),
      fetch(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/routes.dat"
      )
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((d) => d3.csvParseRows(d, routeParse)),
    ]).then(([airports, routes]) => {
      const byIata = indexBy(airports, "iata", false);

      const filteredRoutes = routes
        .filter(
          (d) =>
            byIata.hasOwnProperty(d.srcIata) && byIata.hasOwnProperty(d.dstIata)
        )
        .filter((d) => d.stops === "0")
        .map((d) =>
          Object.assign(d, {
            srcAirport: byIata[d.srcIata],
            dstAirport: byIata[d.dstIata],
          })
        )
        .filter(
          (d) =>
            d.srcAirport.country === COUNTRY && d.dstAirport.country !== COUNTRY
        );

      setAirports(airports);
      setRoutes(filteredRoutes);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    globeEl.current.pointOfView({ lat: 42, lng: -71, altitude: 2 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Globe
      ref={globeEl}
      width={1000}
      height={1000}
      showGlobe={true}
      globeImageUrl={earth}
      backgroundImageUrl={background}
      arcsData={routes}
      arcStartLat={(d) => +d.srcAirport.lat}
      arcStartLng={(d) => +d.srcAirport.lng}
      arcEndLat={(d) => +d.dstAirport.lat}
      arcEndLng={(d) => +d.dstAirport.lng}
      arcDashLength={0.25}
      arcDashGap={1}
      arcDashInitialGap={() => Math.random()}
      arcDashAnimateTime={4000}
      arcColor={(d) => [
        `rgba(48, 64, 77, ${OPACITY})`,
        `rgba(191, 204, 214, ${OPACITY})`,
      ]}
      arcsTransitionDuration={0}
      pointsData={airports}
      pointColor={() => "white"}
      pointAltitude={0}
      pointRadius={0.03}
      pointsMerge={true}
    />
  );
}

export default GlobeHome;
```

which I then import into `Boxes.js`:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "react-three-fiber";
import Globe from './Globe'

function Box(props) {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
  const mesh = useRef();
  // Set up state for the hovered and active state
  const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  // Rotate mesh every frame, this is outside of React without overhead
  useFrame(() => {
    mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
  });
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
    >
      <Globe />
    </mesh>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <spotLight position={[10, 10, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} />
      <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} />
      <Box />
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

Using this approach gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught "Div" is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend it?
```

Thoughts on de-bugging? Is there a better way of rotating this Globe.gl globe?

Comment: Why are you creating `GlobeHome` if you never use it in `Box`?

Comment: Am I not? `GlobeHome` is the function that creates the globe. I export that from `Globe.js` and import it as `Globe`, which then goes into the `Box` function. I then try to render the `Box` function in App. Hope this clarifies

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that. You are using it. That error implies that somewhere in your code you're trying to use something named `THREE.Div`, but this doesn't natively exist in the library. Maybe you, or `react-three-fiber` is trying to use `THREE.Div` before creating it?

Comment: Perhaps. I'll check and follow up

Comment: I think the problem is that both react-globe.gl and react-three-fiber both try to create a three.js canvas scene in a DOM node div and the `Globe` component is not a mesh that you can put inside a react-three-fiber component as a child as they aren't compatible. To rotate the globe try using the `pointOfView` property of Globe https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-globe.gl#utility

Answer (score 2):

Into you `Globe.js` component, inside `useEffect()` add this: `globeEl.current.controls().autoRotate = true;`

Regarding your error, its something else. You need to read [this](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/2719)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. The problem is that you're passing the Globe component as a property of the Box component which is a mesh. The Box component is then in the Canvas component. This library requires that you place the Globe component as a standard React component outside of the Canvas component. I was able to fix the issue in my logic by changing the App component to just return <Globe ...> with its properties and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of @react-three/fiber does not support shadowMap as the prop in Canvas instead we must use shadows props in the canvas.
But the shadow can also be achieved using the  element in jsx which is imported from "@react-three/dier" : https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#contactshadows

```
 <canvas shadows>
    {/*This is the shadow generating element imported from @react-three/drei */}
    <ContactShadows opacity={1} scale={10} blur={1} far={10} resolution={256} color="#000000" />

{/*You must have shadow generating and shadow receiving objects but not the ContactShadows element to support shadows genereated by lights*/}
    </canvas>
```